# Re-invoke $.ajax under condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ajaxq

When I initialize an ajax call, when the request is succeeded and match a condition I want to re-call it again inside it, like following:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success  :  function(){
                    if(true)
                        // run_this_request_again();
                },
    // or,
    complete : function(){
                    if(true)
                        // run_this_request_again();
                },
    ...
});
```

Comment: Wrap your AJAX call in a function and call it from within the `success` callback if you want to execute it again

Answer (score 1):

Create a `function` and place you ajax code in it. Call that function wherever you required.

```
function ajaxCall()
{
    //Your ajax code here
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success:function()
        {
            if(true)
                ajaxCall()
        },
        complete : function()
        {
            if(true)
                ajaxCall()
        },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `this` inside success with the ajax method.

```
$.ajax({
  success: function() {
    if (true)
      $.ajax(this);
  },
  complete: function() {
    if (true)
      $.ajax(this);
  }
});
```